# How to test JPA queries?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, netbeans

I'm developing a website with JSF with JPA.
So I configure a DataSource in my Glassfish instance and in my project too.

But I wonder, how can I test my JPA queries in Eclipse ?

In Netbeans, for example, you just have to do a right-click on the `hibernate.cfg` file and *"Run HQL queries"* (translating)
There's something like this in Eclipse ?

**UPDATE:**
Following the comments I install the Hibernate Tools then try to use the HQL Editor, but gives me this strange error below :

[image: configuration]

[image: error]

Any idea how can I solve this ?

Just to make myself clear, this is my JPA configuration :
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
I did what @kenChan recommend but it seems that I have one error left: (I didn't know that I have to put the MySQL driver in the classpath, in Hibernate Tools configuration, tkanks KenChan.)

[image]
The error:
[image]

**UPDATE 3:**
@KenChan I tried to create a property file (I found a similar problem topic [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2400465)) but still gives the same error:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 4:**
IT WORKS!

I was missing one 's' in the end of this line:

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class
```

In the end my hibernate.properties stay this way:

```
hibernate.connection.password=***********
hibernate.connection.username=*******
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc\:mysql\://********\:3306/********
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider
hibernate.datasource=
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
```

Thank you @KenChan by your support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes . You can install [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) , which is an eclipse plugin designed for hibernate 3 .It provides the editor for  writing, editing and executing query written in HQL or  Criteria API.

See [this](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.M5/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#hql_and_criteria_editors) for more information

Regarding to your errors , you should import the MySQL JDBC Driver in the **ClassPath** tab when editing the hibernate configuration.

Comment: But for this my project should be configured as Hibernate, but it's with JPA (EJB 3) and datasource on it.
It works with Hibernate Tools too ?

Comment: @ValterHenrique: If you are using Netbeans defaults, you are probably using EclipseLink, not JPA. Both EclipseLink and Hibernate are JPA implementations. You can switch between them in Persistence.xml

Comment: Actually I'm using Generics 2.0 in my project, so if I switch to EclipseLink should work then ?

Comment: do you import  MySQL JDBC Driver in the ClassPath tab when editing the hibernate configuration ?? The error message says that it cannot find the JDBC Driver

Comment: @KenChan I did what you said, it seems that the errors are lesser now, but still have one error.

Comment: I think if no files are selected in the `property file` or `persistent unit` fields in the hibernate tool 's configuration,the setting from the selected project will be used.From the error message,I think your project is getting the transaction manager from the application server now.I suggest you to made another `property file` or `persistent unit` configuration such that your project can be run without the application server and select these files in the  `property file` or `persistent unit` fields in the hibernate tool 's configuration to overrides the settings in the project

Comment: @KenChan I update my post, could you please take a look  ?
Thanks.

Comment: The today's link seems to be: https://tools.jboss.org/features/hibernate.html

(alexander by May 19 '15 at 14:16 marked it broken; and it is still broken)